# SQL select all the orders for employees with minimum sales

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm attempting to select all the employees with minimum sales from the following database schema:

> Employees(eno, ename, zip, hdate)
>
> Parts(pno, pname, qoh, price, level)
>
> Customers(cno, cname, street, zip, phone)
>
> Orders(ono, cno, eno, received, shipped)
>
> Odetails(ono, pno, qty)
>
> Zipcodes(zip, city)

I can't get the query I was working on to work for total sales per employee without an error.  My problem is getting the quantity * price per order related to the employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be something like this:

```
SELECT Employees.eno, Employees.ename, SUM(Odetails.qty * Parts.price) AS Sales
FROM Employees JOIN
 Orders ON Employees.eno = Orders.eno JOIN
 Odetails ON Orders.ono = Odetails.ono JOIN
 Parts ON Parts.pno = Odetails.pno
GROUP BY Employees.eno, Employees.ename
```

The above select query (SQL Server) would return a list of Employees with their respective eno (guessing Employee Number) and ename along with the SUM of their qty multipled against the price of the part, then you'll be able to determine the employees with minimum sales. You could use the select above as a derived table and then sort by the Sales column to see the order of who had the least sales, second least, third etc. I left the joins simply as 'JOIN' because I don't know your database because it could be an INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN.

Hope this helps mate.